Import transistor into LTSpice
I would like to import this transistor -> RFD16N06LE (datasheet: https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/67811/INTERSIL/RFD16N06LE.html) into LTSpice; the datasheet has a PSPICE model written out for it, but I'm not sure how to actually import it in? I've tried just copy pasting it into notepad and saving as .asc but LTSpice is saying there is a syntax error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

If you put the text in the question then we can see what you have. Also put the specific error you are getting.

Similar question has been answered here.
You encountered an error because of a missing dot before the SUBCKT. I have corrected it in the script below. Save it in a folder and name it as RFD16N06LE.lib.
* This model comes from here: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/67811/INTERSIL/RFD16N06LE.html
* rev 8/2/9
.SUBCKT RFD16N06LE  2 1 3
CA  12  8 1.46e-9
CB  15  14 1.46e-9
CIN  6  8 1.0e-9
DBODY 7 5 DBODYMOD
DBREAK 5 11  DBREAKMOD
DPLCAP 10 5 DPLCAPMOD
EBREAK 11 7 17  18 66.0
EDS  14  8  5  8 1
EGS  13  8  6  8 1
ESG 6 10 6 8 1
EVTHRES 6 21 19 8  1
EVTEMP 20 6 18 22 1
IT  8  17  1
LDRAIN 2 5 1e-9
LGATE 1  9 5.5e-9
LSOURCE  3  7 4.4e-9
MMED 16 6 8 8 MMEDMOD
MSTRO 16 6 8 8 MSTROMOD
MWEAK 16 21 8 8 MWEAKMOD
RBREAK  17  18  RBREAKMOD  1
RDRAIN 50 16 RDRAINMOD 7.0e-3
RGATE  9  20 3.6
RLDRAIN 2 5 10
RLGATE 1 9 55
RLSOURCE 3 7 44
RSLC1 5 51 RSLCMOD 1e-6
RSLC2 5 50 1e3
RSOURCE  8  7  RSOURCEMOD 1.45e-2
RVTHRES 22 8 RVTHRESMOD  1
RVTEMP 18 19 RVTEMPMOD 1
S1A  6  12  13  8  S1AMOD
S1B  13  12  13  8  S1BMOD
S2A  6  15  14  13  S2AMOD
S2B  13  15  14  13  S2BMOD
VBAT 22 19  DC  1
ESLC 51 50 VALUE={(V(5,51)/ABS(V(5,51)))*(PWR(V(5,51)/(1e-6*100),3.5))}
.MODEL DBODYMOD D (IS = 6.3e-13  RS = 6.8e-3  TRS1 = 1e-3  TRS2 = 1e-6  XTI = 4.3 CJO = 1.28e-9  TT = 5.1e-8 M = 0.5)
.MODEL DBREAKMOD D (RS = 2.9e-1  TRS1 = 1e-4  TRS2 = 0)
.MODEL DPLCAPMOD D (CJO = 9.5e-10  IS = 1e-30   N = 10 M = 0.82)
.MODEL MMEDMOD NMOS (VTO = 2.10 KP = 6 IS = 1e-30 N = 10 TOX = 1 L = 1u W = 1u RG = 3.6)
.MODEL MSTROMOD NMOS (VTO = 2.45 KP = 60.5 IS = 1e-30 N = 10 TOX = 1 L = 1u W = 1u)
.MODEL MWEAKMOD NMOS (VTO = 1.79 KP = 0.13 IS = 1e-30 N = 10 TOX = 1 L = 1u W = 1u RG = 36 RS = 0.1)
.MODEL RBREAKMOD RES (TC1 = 1.2e-3  TC2 = -5e-7)
.MODEL RDRAINMOD RES (TC1 = 1.3e-2  TC2 = 3.1e-5)
.MODEL RSLCMOD RES (TC1 = 5.5e-3 TC2 = 7e-6)
.MODEL RSOURCEMOD RES (TC1 = 1e-3 TC2 = 1e-6)
.MODEL RVTHRESMOD RES (TC1 = -1.8e-3 TC2 = -5.8e-6)
.MODEL RVTEMPMOD RES (TC1 = -1.7e-3  TC2 = 8e-7)
.MODEL S1AMOD VSWITCH (RON = 1e-5  ROFF = 0.1  VON = -4.8  VOFF= -2.8)
.MODEL S1BMOD VSWITCH (RON = 1e-5  ROFF = 0.1  VON = -2.8  VOFF= -4.8)
.MODEL S2AMOD VSWITCH (RON = 1e-5  ROFF = 0.1  VON = -0.6  VOFF= 0.5)
.MODEL S2BMOD VSWITCH (RON = 1e-5  ROFF = 0.1  VON = 0.5  VOFF= -0.6)
.ENDS

Save the following LTSpice example file as Test_NMOS.asc in the same folder.
Version 4
SHEET 1 920 680
WIRE 144 16 48 16
WIRE 144 32 144 16
WIRE 48 64 48 16
WIRE 144 128 144 112
WIRE 48 176 48 144
WIRE 176 176 48 176
WIRE 48 192 48 176
WIRE -48 272 -48 256
WIRE 0 272 -48 272
WIRE -48 288 -48 272
WIRE 48 304 48 288
WIRE -48 384 -48 368
FLAG 144 128 0
FLAG 48 304 0
FLAG 176 176 out1
IOPIN 176 176 Out
FLAG -48 384 0
FLAG -48 256 in1
IOPIN -48 256 In
SYMBOL nmos 0 192 R0
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMATTR Value RFD16N06LE
SYMATTR Prefix X
SYMBOL res 32 48 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL voltage 144 16 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL voltage -48 272 M0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 3.3 0 7n 7n 10u 20u)
TEXT -376 32 Left 2 !.INCLUDE RFD16N06LE.lib
TEXT -160 392 Left 2 !.tran 1m

Open the Test_NMOS.asc in LTSpice and run. You should get the following result if you double-click on out1 and in1 labels.

